# Void Pointers : how to use as a general class pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers

I have two cpp classes let's say ClassA and ClassB. I have two pointers that points accordingly to that classes, let's say pointerA and pointerB. Now I have a generic void* pointer that I want to point either ClassA or to ClassB depending some conditions. In this case get error  error C2227: left of '->GetPosition' must point to class/struct/union/generic type type is 'void *'.

How to avoid this kind of errors ?

```
ClassA { 
   void GetPosition();
}

ClassB { 
   void GetPosition();
}

main() {

   ClassA  *pointerA;
   ClassB  *pointerB;
   void    *generic_pointerAorB;

   pointerA = GetAddrOfClassA();
   pointerB = GetAddrOfClassB()

   generic_pointer = pointerA;

   //********************** error at the code below ******************************
   //error C2227: left of '->GetPosition' must point to class/struct/union/generic type. 
   //type is 'void *'

   generic_pointer->GetPosition(); 

   //*****************************************************************************



}
```

Comment: first cast the pointer to the proper type.

Comment: Define a base class for both that defines the common virtual functions you want to use. You're trying to do ducktyping in C++; it won't work :)

Comment: Also shouldn't `generic_pointerAorB` simply be `generic_pointer`? As of right now `generic_pointer` is not declared.

Comment: This smells like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . tell us what you're *really* trying to do (and not how).

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

Comment: @heinrichj you can implement ducktyping in C++, and it will work. It's quite simple to do with templates :)

Comment: I did the cast from the very begining. It doesnt work. What I am trying to do is that : I have two libraries MCI and DirectShow. I want one generic pointer to point to one of that classes according to some conditions. If DShow works then pointerA is valid,  else pointerB is valid. Now, I want to avoid using If-else checking which one of them is valid. So one generic pointer it will always valid since one of them it will also be valid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `void` pointer doesn't have a method called `GetPosition`, and the pointer itself can't possibly know it's pointing to one of your classes, since it stores the memory address, not the type. You need to use a cast:

```
reinterpret_cast<ClassA*>(generic_pointerAorB)->GetPosition();
```

But to be honest, you should do something else - derive the classes from some base class which has an `virtual GetPosition()` method, and then declare a pointer to the base class.

```
class Base{
   virtual void GetPosition();

ClassA: public Base { 
   void GetPosition();
}

ClassB: public Base { 
   void GetPosition();
}

main(){
   Base* basePointer;
   // <-- other code here
   basePointer = pointerA;
   basePointer->GetPosition();
```

Comment: The 1st solution with reinterpret_cast  is not an accepted solution since I dont want to specify what class to use all the time. What I did in my code is that : generic_pointerAorB = dynamic_cast<ClassA*>(pointerA); I want to say to the compiler that generic_pointerAorB now is pointing to the ClassA. What is the right solution for that ?

Now about the virtual functions from the base class I thought it before your recommendation, but I think its overkill and beside of that there is nothing common between ClassA and ClassB. Dont liked at all :-(

Comment: Both classes define a method with the same name - that __is__ what connects them. And it's totally __not__ an overkill in this particular case. Moreover - there's really no way to do it without a base class. You can think of the base class in the same way as of a Java interface. Remember also that C++ lets you use multiple inheritance, so you can derive the classes from more than one base class, if you need.

Comment: I decided to create a base class. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dereference a `void *` type.

The reason is simple, the compiler cannot know by `void *` type that how much memory is actually pointed to by `generic_pointer` (in your case).

Use it this way:

`((ClassA*)generic_pointer)->GetPosition();`

or equivalently,

`((ClassB*)generic_pointer)->GetPosition();`

Comment: I realize this will technically work, but I wouldn't encourage that kind of code. Also, the compiler needs to know a whole lot more than the size of the object; it also needs its layout in memory.

Comment: The compiler doesnt need to know anything about the memory of the class because the class is already created. It should just point to that class that as i already said is created at the heap somewhere in my code. I want to say to the compiler, just point to that address in the memeory. Remember that all pointers are constant in size and have either 32 or 64 bit data size depending the OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++, a better way to do it would be to define a dummy base class

```
class Base
{
public:
   virtual void GetPosition();
};
```

Then derive both ClassA and ClassB from Base

```
class ClassA: public Base
{
   void GetPosition();
}

class ClassB: public Base
{
   void GetPosition();
}
```

Then in your program instead of declaring void*, use Base*;

```
Base* generic_pointer;
```

Then instead of casting,

```
generic_pointer->GetPosition();
```

Comment: check the commend I wrote to @Paweł Stawarz